# mod_rewrite index.php with various parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url structure:

```
index.php?m=super_blog
index.php?m=super_blog&p=my-first-blog-post
```

I want to set up a mod_rewrite rule in my htaccess file, that would effectively make these URLs work:

```
/blog
/blog/my-first-blog-post
```

This usually happens automatically when I use Drupal, but now I'm using WHMCS. So I believe I would need to add my own custom htaccess rewrite rules.

Any idea how to get this going? Or is it something that happens in code as well? Not just in htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds pretty straight forward so here is a suggestion to get you started. Please note that this site expects you to be able to code yourself, we are only here to assist. Since we do not know your precise situation and requirement you can only give hints.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?blog/?$ /index.php?m=super_blog [END]
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(\w+)/?$ /index.php?m=super_blog&p=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).